# NSCollectionView with vibrant background

Tags: swift, macos, background, nsscrollview, nscollectionview

I'm trying to get an `NSCollectionView` in my application to use a vibrant (semi-blurred transparent) background. I've successfully implemented this for other views by simply adding the view (for instance a label or a progress indicator) to an `NSVisualEffectView`. I've also tried this on the `NSCollectionViewItem` view that is used by the `NSCollectionView` to render its contents. This also works.

But I cannot get the `NSCollectionView` to use a vibrant background. I've tried this by adding the `NSScrollView` that contains the NSCollectionView to an `NSVisualEffectView` but this does not work. I've also set the `drawsBackground` property to false (both in Interface Builder and programatically: `collectionScrollView?.drawsBackground = false`, and `collectionScrollView?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()`.

The view hierarchy is:

```
Window
- View
  - Split View
    - Custom View (with a source list)
    - Custom View
      - Visual Effect View
        - Scroll View
          - Clip View
            - Collection View
```

NB. I've also tried changing the background color of the `NSScrollView` that contains the `NSCollectionView` to any other color (e.g. red) but this also does not work (either in Interface Builder or programatically). The background stays white.

Comment: Have you tried changing the background of your `NSCollectionView` itself?

Comment: @sschale Iit was that simple. Apparently I assumed that I could not set the background colour because the option was not available in Interface Builder. But I can set the background colour using `
        collectionView?.backgroundColors = [NSColor.clearColor()]`. Thank you!

Comment: Wow. Thanks to @Dieudonné I finally can make the NSCollectionView with transparent background. I did notice the property >backgroundColorS<. THANK YOU !

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are correct, but it's important to note that an `NSCollectionView` is embedded in an `NSScrollView` which has its own background. The solution is to set the collection view’s background to clear AND set the enclosing scroll view to not draw its background. This can be done in Interface Builder or else with the second line of code below.

```
collectionView.backgroundColors = @[[NSColor clearColor]];
collectionView.enclosingScrollView.drawsBackground = NO;
```

Of course, be sure that no other superview is drawing an opaque background (e.g. set a parent view’s class to be `NSVisualEffectView`.

More details can be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058337/transparent-nscollectionview-background) (basically the same question).