# Transparent NSCollectionView Background

Tags: swift, background-color, nscollectionview

I'm again struggling with setting NSViews background colors to transparent. I have a `NSCollectionView` as part of `NSClipView` which is part of a  `NSScrollview`. My `MainViewController` has an outlet to the `collectionView`. With adding the two lines of code and after compiling the background is sometimes transparent but most of the times not:

```
view.wantsLayer = true
collectionView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
```

I also tried to select/de-select the "Draw Background" property of the `NSScrollView` in the IB without any effects.
What do I miss here.

Comment: Cocoa is not so kind as UIKit.  Yet, it'd just be the matter of creating a subclass.

Comment: El Tomato, thanks for the response. What do I need to subclass and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I struggled a bit attempting to get my NSCollectionView background "transparent" @JFS solution pointed me in the right direction: and I finally achieved it by setting **both** the parent scrollView and the collectionView backgrounds:

```
cvScrollView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
collectionView.backgroundColors = [NSColor.clear]
```

Answer (score 8):

Ok, after a long evil trial and error phase I found a solution at least for myself. There are two background colors to set in order to have the proper behavior:

1. the background color of the `NSScrollView`:

[image]

2. the `NSCollectionView` primary color:

[image]

Both have to be set appropriately. At the point I set both to the same color I got the background I want. With setting only the ScrollView background color there was still the white background when scrolling the items in the CollectionView.

Answer (score 5):

To make clear background for `NSScrollView`, the best option in Swift 4.2 is "Not draw a background". Let's get to view a programmatically example:

```
let scrollView = NSScrollView()
scrollView.drawsBackground = false
scrollView.contentView.drawsBackground = false
```

`NSCollectionView` has background for sections, so you need to specify colors for sections

```
let collectionView = NSCollectionView()
collectionView.backgroundColors = [.clear]
```

If you set `backgroundColors` to `nil` or to empty array, the background color is set by default to white.

If you set a background view for `NSCollectionView`, this array is ignored

You could try to put a `NSView` with `frame` zero as a `backgroundView` for `NSCollectionView`